# Tomcat RemoteIpValve with IIS 7 via ARR

Tags: iis-7.5, tomcat7, arr

I'm trying to setup IIS 7.5 as reverse proxy to connect to Tomcat 7 via ARR 3.

For some reason when IIS forwards the request, the x-forwarded-for header contains the remote port, so instead of showing something like:  123.124.125.126  I see  123.124.125.126:54321

Unfortunately that does not work with RemoteIpValve, which expects the IP address only.

Is there a way to remove the port from IIS?  or in RemoteIpValve?

**Update:** I tried running the command below and I can see that it updated applicationHost.config but I still see the port number (restarted IIS):

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /includePortInXForwardedFor:"false" /commit:apphost
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following workaround:

On IIS, in %System32%/inetsrv/config/applicationHost.config I added the following snippet at system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/rule [name=ARR*]:

```
<severVariables>
  <set name="HTTP_X_REMOTE_ADDR" value="{REMOTE_ADDR}" />
</severVariables>
```

Then I specified that name to the RemoteIpValve in Tomcat's server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-remote-addr" />
```

To use the newly added header instead of X-Forwarded-For